# Javascript - Adding line breaks to array strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, line-breaks

I have a script that displays a random sentence on button click.
I would like to add a line break to some of the sentences. Example:

"This is the first sentence"

becomes:

"This is
the first sentence"

I have tried using `\n` and `<br>`, but none works.
What else could I try?

```js
    const p = document.getElementById("sentences");
    const origSentences = ["This is the first sentence.", "This is the second sentence.", "This is the third sentence."];
    let remainingSentences = [];

    function randomSentence() {
        if (remainingSentences.length === 0) remainingSentences = origSentences.slice();
        const {
            length
        } = remainingSentences;
        const [quote] = remainingSentences.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * length), 1);
        p.textContent = quote;
    }
```

```html
<p><button onclick="randomSentence()" type="button">Random Sentence</button></p>
<p id="sentences"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign your quote to the `textContent` field of your paragraph `p`, it will be rendered as plain text.  If you instead use `innerHTML`, it will parse and render any HTML you provide.

See example.

```js
const p = document.getElementById("sentences");
const origSentences = [
  "This is the <br /> first sentence.",
  "This is the second sentence.",
  "This is the <br /> third sentence."
];
let remainingSentences = [];

function randomSentence() {
  if (remainingSentences.length === 0)
    remainingSentences = origSentences.slice();
  const { length } = remainingSentences;
  const [quote] = remainingSentences.splice(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * length),
    1
  );
  p.innerHTML = quote;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button 
    onclick="randomSentence()" 
    type="button">
    Random Sentence
  </button>
</p>

<p id="sentences"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! It fixed my problem! I was unaware of that difference between textContent and innerHTML. I guess I still have a lot to study.